# extending aspnet identity to include additional properties for WEB FORMS

Tags: c#, security, code-first, asp.net-identity

i am currently implementing aspnet identity(code first) for WEB FORMS(VS 2013) i would like to know how to add additional properties like date of birth to the entity.

i can currently do this via MVC but have issues on aspnet WEBFORMS.

Comment: There should be absolutely no difference between Web Forms and MVC in this regard.  What issues are you having?

Comment: when i run enable-migrations on the package manager console i get an error message that "No context type was found in the assembly". But when i run same command for mvc it runs.

Comment: Then you obviously aren't including the context in your assembly.  Even so, that has nothing to do with Identity.  That's a migrations problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class which inherits from [IdentityUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and add your custom properties to it. An example would look like the following

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The next step would be to change your database context to use this new user

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  ...
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem you should post what your issues actually are.